# MATLAB delete rows dynamically in array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

> I have an array which has 0s in random spots, I want to create this
>   array without any 0s for example:

```
1
2
3
0
3
4
0
3
should be reduced to:
1
2
3
3
4
3
```

> Is there a good way to delete these rows in MATLAB? The most I could
>   do was move these values up in the array, but I was wondering if there
>   was something as "un-linking"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of the vector is v;

Then just

```
v = v(v~=0)
```

would do.